# Structuring the axios callback in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, babeljs, axios

### Question

What am I missing or doing wrong in my code if I just want to display a joke in my project?

[WIP demo on codepen](https://codepen.io/JGallardo/pen/wxwZyj)

---

Sample JSON response

[image]

#### HTML

```
<div class="jokes" v-for="joke in jokes">
  <h2>{{ joke.setup }}</h2>
  <p>{{ joke.line }}</p>
</div>
```

#### JS - babel

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data:{
    jokes: []
  },
  created(){
    this.GetJokes();  
  },
  methods: {
     GetJokes () {
      axios.get('https://08ad1pao69.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/random_joke')
      .then(response => {

          let joke = response.data[0];

          let apiInfo = {
            setup: joke.setup,
            line: joke.punchline
          };
          this.jokes.push(apiInfo)
      })
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your response is not an array. You just need

```
let joke = response.data
```

And that will fix your code.

Here is your [pen updated](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/ajorJW?editors=1010).

Comment: What can i do to replace the previous joke with the new one? in that pen, a new joke is added every time the button is pushed.

Comment: @JGallardo Don't store the jokes in an array, just use an object. Updated the pen in example. https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/ajorJW?editors=1010